# fdisk and parted won't work on a USB stick with Fedora 23 alpha 2 x86_64

Tags: storage, fedora, fdisk, parted, usb-boot

So I burned a Fedora 23 alpha 2 on a 16GB USB stick through

```
 dd if=path/to/fedora.iso of=/dev/usb_device bs=512
```

I used `bs=512` because the sectors on the stick are 512 bytes.
Opening the stick in fdisk gives me the warning:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/xvdi'! 
The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

Continuing in fdisk is useless, given the totally impossible parameters it returns:

```
Device     Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdi1   *           0     2928639     1464320    0  Empty
/dev/xvdi2             172        8695        4262   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/xvdi3            8776       42919       17072    0  Empty
```

It is clear that partition 1 does overlap 2 and 3.
However, if I use (GNU) parted, I get the warning:

```
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes,
but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?"
```

Which gives impossible sizes upon ignore.
I would like to add an additional partition on the USB stick, but given the way both fdisk and parted behave, that seems rather impossible to me.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

[This article](https://serverfault.com/questions/549158/creating-bootable-fedora-usb-with-persistent-storage) also deals with the problem, but the solutions mentioned there don't work (for me), and I have no (enough) rights to comment.
Reassembling the iso file keeps giving it a Apple label in the GPT on which both fdisk and parted fail.
(Why) Isn't it possible to just have this 1.5GB iso written to USB with msdos or fat32 file system? Or any other solution would be most welcome.

Comment: Use the [Live USB Creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/).

Comment: Live USB Creator doesn't recognise the filesystem after the initial burning with 'dd'. Even after mkfs ext4 /path/to/usb/stick **and** creating a primary 1st partition with ext4 using fdisk and giving it the bootable flag, Live USB Creator tells me it doesn't recognise the file system and advises to reformat, which I just had done, I believe... So, no, Live USB Creator doesn't work.